# Can I specify a port on a COM object server URL?

Tags: com, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am attempting to create a COM object from a remote source in Coldfusion and I'm running into a lot of errors.  I am running 32 bit coldfusion because 64 bit does not support COM objects so I know that isn't the issue.

My question is can I specify a port in the server path in a `<cfobject>` tag?

I currently have (and yes, for the example I'm pointing to localhost):

```
<cfobject name="QBSession" type="COM" class="{6C8E45LC-B9MM-22LR-A223-50BMGBD45ACP}" action="create" context="remote" server="http://127.0.0.1" >
```

Can I put `server="http://127.0.0.1:80"`?  Or will this cause further issues. I want to be able to specify a single port for the server to listen to for added security.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to be able to point to a remote CF server for the source of your cfobject?

I also am kind of shocked that 64 bit won't support com?  You sure on that?

Comment: Maybe he meant to say *"..64-bit does not support 32-bit com objects"* ..?

Comment: @Limey & @Leigh - No.  Per the documentation 64-bit does not support COM objects at all.  [Here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3208083) is one of the posts that discusses it.

But to further answer your question, I would like to point the object at a remote server to access data from it and I'd like to further specify a port to go through.

Comment: @JimP - Not urgent, but do you know where in the documentation it says that? I cannot seem to find anything beyond unofficial posts. Maybe my google is broken ;)

Comment: @Leigh - I haven't seen anything confirming or denying it in official posts as of yet.  But it seems to have come up enough times in other arenas that I'll accept it as possible until I find otherwise.  But on that note, I'm now trying to do the same procedure from a 32 bit machine so it doesn't matter what bit-level it supports.  I simply get a response of `The cause of this exception was that: AutomationException: 0x80070005 - General access denied error. `  Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @JimP - Sounds reasonable. Unfortunately I am not great w/cryptic COM errors. Did you check your cf logs for additional details? Might also check the o/s logs too (ie windows event log, etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer seems to be that you cannot specify a port when creating a COM object.

The 64-bit question is still unanswered.  I haven't found Adobe documentation supporting nor denying my earlier assertions, I have only found web posts that support it.

The other interesting thing is that apparently CF does not like to instantiate COM objects on different servers.  Meaning I cannot pull an object from one server and instantiate it on another.  I'm sure some of you knew this already but I am putting this up as a reference for all of us who didn't.

Hope this helps.